# got HTTPError while imporing

Tags: smartpy, fa2

i am getting http error while importing fa2 library. i checked link and it says host error. did it moved to new address?
File "./contracts/src/something.py", line 3, in 
FA2 = sp.io.import_script_from_url("https://smartpy.io/templates/fa2_lib.py")
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 526:

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `io.import_template("fa2_lib.py")` instead. Now (and until there is a package system for SmartPy), for production, I even suggest to copy the library in local and import it directly.

The fa2 library is now upgraded to the new syntax.
If you want to access the legacy syntax go to https://legacy.smartpy.io/.